# Mass "Change Owner" case list-view button not showing on Community?

Tags: list-view, case-object, list-button

In our lightning community, we cannot figure out why the mass "Change Owner" button is not showing on a list-view within our community.

---

1. In Case search layouts, the mass "Change Owner" button is enabled.
2. Enabled permissions in the profile created for this community:

- Access to the Case Object
- case management (create, modify)
- access to the Owner Id field

3. Furthermore, even the single "Change Owner" button is available to users on the case layout page

---

**What are we missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the Change Owner button on related lists isn't visible in Lightning Experience or Communities at all.